# Django 1.8, Postgis Querying distance between two points

Tags: python, django, distance, postgis, django-1.8

In a tutorial i saw the distance calculation between a given point and points in db.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance
```

But Django 1.8 didn't have above "functions" module. So how can i achieve the same result as the query below in 1.8

```
qs = qs.annotate(distance=Distance('location', pnt)).order_by('distance')
```

I looked at Geo database api docs. But i got confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django 1.8 you should use `GeoQuerySet.distance()` method, take a look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-queries